# print an array vertically

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I recently found out how to print an array vertically but I have yet to find out how to choose when to increment it

```
array = ['1', '2', '3', '5', '7', '11', '13',]
array = map(str,array)
array = list(array)
print("\n".join(array))
```

output example:

```
1
2
3
5
7
11
13
```

output goal:

```
1, 2, 3, 5, 7,
11, 13,
```

Comment: just use a for loop and print each element in the array. What is your goal? Just printing those numbers like that? YOu have to explain why you want to print them and how

Comment: Is there a reason you want a trailing comma at the end of each line?

Answer (score 1):

```
array = ['1', '2', '3', '5', '7', '11', '13',]
for i in range(len(array)):
    print(array[i], end=', ')
    if i % 5 == 4:
        print()
```

Comment: Please explain to help viewers understand what it does. (there is nothing in the question, btw)

Comment: The question was about vertically printed array with new line on every 5 element

Answer (score 0):

To perform the desired print out of the provided array, this will work (with the addition of a newline in between):

```
array = ['1', '2', '3', '5', '7', '11', '13']

for n in array[:-2]:
    print(n + ',', end=' ')

print('\n')

for n in array[-2:]:
    print(n + ',', end=' ')
```

Returns:

```
1, 2, 3, 5, 7,

11, 13,
```